# Activity Reloads with Previous Selected Data Bug

Tags: java, android, json, sharedpreferences, android-spinner

So i developed an android news app. A spinner item is available on the toolbar and data reloads according to spinner selection. However, when the data reloads, for some of the items, it directly loads the relevant content but for some others, it loads the previously selected spinner data. Current data for the current item only shows after reloading same spinner data using the swipe refresh functionality which i had implemented. I want the correct data relevant to that selection to load the first time itself without having to refresh all the time.

Below is my MainActivity where all these functions are called.

```
package com.example.app.activities;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
import android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.DefaultRetryPolicy;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.RetryPolicy;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.example.app.Config;
import com.example.app.R;
import com.example.app.fragment.FragmentCategory;
import com.example.app.fragment.FragmentFavorite;
import com.example.app.fragment.FragmentProfile;
import com.example.app.fragment.FragmentRecent;
import com.example.app.fragment.FragmentVideo;
import com.example.app.utils.AppBarLayoutBehavior;
import com.example.app.utils.Constant;
import com.example.app.utils.GDPR;
import uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyConfig;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


String URL="url" //outputs JSON data

private long exitTime = 0;
MyApplication myApplication;
View view;
private BottomNavigationView navigation;
public ViewPager viewPager;
private Toolbar toolbar;
MenuItem prevMenuItem;
int pager_number = 5;
BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver;
Spinner mySpinner;
ArrayList<String> spinnerConstituencyName;
int spinConstID;
private PrefManager prefManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //Set Font
    CalligraphyConfig.initDefault(new CalligraphyConfig.Builder()
            .setDefaultFontPath("fonts/Arkhip_font.ttf")
            .setFontAttrId(R.attr.fontPath)
            .build());
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    view = findViewById(android.R.id.content);

    if (Config.ENABLE_RTL_MODE) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            getWindow().getDecorView().setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
        }
    }

    AppBarLayout appBarLayout = findViewById(R.id.tab_appbar_layout);
    ((CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) appBarLayout.getLayoutParams()).setBehavior(new AppBarLayoutBehavior());

    myApplication = MyApplication.getInstance();

    toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle(R.string.app_name);

    spinnerConstituencyName = new ArrayList<>();
    mySpinner = findViewById(R.id.mySpinner);
    prefManager = new PrefManager(MainActivity.this);
    loadSpinnerData(URL);

    mySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        int check = 0;
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            /*String spinConstituency = mySpinner.getItemAtPosition(mySpinner.getSelectedItemPosition()).toString();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), spinConstituency, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();*/

            if (++check > 1) {
                Intent intent = getIntent(); //MainActivity
                String itemSelected = mySpinner.getItemAtPosition(mySpinner.getSelectedItemPosition()).toString();
                //TODO: DONE
                //intent.putExtra("NAME_KEY", itemSelected);
                prefManager.spinWriteString(itemSelected);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Constituency News Now Showing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }

    });

    viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(pager_number);

    navigation = findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.navigation_home:
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_category:
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_video:
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_favorite:
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(3);
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_profile:
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(4);
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            if (prevMenuItem != null) {
                prevMenuItem.setChecked(false);
            } else {
                navigation.getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(false);
            }
            navigation.getMenu().getItem(position).setChecked(true);
            prevMenuItem = navigation.getMenu().getItem(position);

            if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() == 1) {
                toolbar.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.title_nav_category));
            } else if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() == 2) {
                toolbar.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.title_nav_video));
            } else if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() == 3) {
                toolbar.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.title_nav_favorite));
            } else if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() == 4) {
                toolbar.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.title_nav_favorite));
            } else {
                toolbar.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });

    if (Config.ENABLE_RTL_MODE) {
        viewPager.setRotationY(180);
    }

    broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            // checking for type intent filter
            if (intent.getAction().equals(Constant.REGISTRATION_COMPLETE)) {
                // now subscribe to global topic to receive app wide notifications
                FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic(Constant.TOPIC_GLOBAL);

            } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Constant.PUSH_NOTIFICATION)) {
                // new push notification is received
                String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Push notification: " + message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    };

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    final String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
    final String imageUrl = intent.getStringExtra("image");
    final long nid = intent.getLongExtra("id", 0);
    final String link = intent.getStringExtra("link");

    if (message != null) {

        LayoutInflater layoutInflaterAndroid = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this);
        View mView = layoutInflaterAndroid.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog_notif, null);

        final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        alert.setView(mView);

        final TextView notification_title = mView.findViewById(R.id.news_title);
        final TextView notification_message = mView.findViewById(R.id.news_message);
        final ImageView notification_image = mView.findViewById(R.id.news_image);

        if (imageUrl.endsWith(".jpg") || imageUrl.endsWith(".jpeg") || imageUrl.endsWith(".png") || imageUrl.endsWith(".gif")) {
            notification_title.setText(message);
            notification_message.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Picasso.with(MainActivity.this)
                    .load(imageUrl.replace(" ", "%20"))
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_thumbnail)
                    .resize(200, 200)
                    .centerCrop()
                    .into(notification_image);

            alert.setPositiveButton(R.string.dialog_read_more, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityNotificationDetail.class);
                    intent.putExtra("id", nid);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
            alert.setNegativeButton(R.string.dialog_dismiss, null);

        } else {
            notification_title.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));

            notification_message.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            notification_message.setText(message);

            notification_image.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "link : " + link, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            if (!link.equals("")) {
                alert.setPositiveButton("Continue", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Intent open = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(link));
                        startActivity(open);
                    }
                });
                alert.setNegativeButton(R.string.dialog_dismiss, null);
            } else {
                alert.setPositiveButton(R.string.dialog_ok, null);
            }
        }

        alert.setCancelable(false);
        alert.show();

    }

    GDPR.updateConsentStatus(this);

}

public class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new FragmentRecent();
            case 1:
                return new FragmentCategory();
            case 2:
                return new FragmentVideo();
            case 3:
                return new FragmentFavorite();
            case 4:
                return new FragmentProfile();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return pager_number;
    }


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
    switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.search:
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivitySearch.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem);
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() != 0) {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem((0), true);
    } else {
        exitApp();
    }
}

public void exitApp() {
    if ((System.currentTimeMillis() - exitTime) > 2000) {
        Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.press_again_to_exit), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        exitTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    } else {
        finish();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}

private int getIndex(Spinner spinner, String myString){

    int index = 0;

    for (int i=0;i < spinner.getCount(); i++) {
        if (spinner.getItemAtPosition(i).equals(myString)) {
            index = i;
        }
    }
    return index;
}

private void loadSpinnerData(String url) {
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            //TODO DONE
            String name = prefManager.spinReadString();

            try{
                JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(response);

                if(jsonObject.getString("status").equals("ok")){
                    JSONArray jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("constituencies");

                    for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                        JSONObject jsonObject1=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        String spinConstituency=jsonObject1.getString("constituency_name");
                        //TODO DONE
                        if (spinConstituency.equals(name))
                            spinConstID = jsonObject1.getInt("const_id");
                            spinnerConstituencyName.add(spinConstituency);
                    }
                    //TODO DONE
                    prefManager.writeString("" + spinConstID);
                }

                ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                        R.layout.custom_spinner_item, spinnerConstituencyName){
                    @Override
                    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,
                                                ViewGroup parent) {
                        View view = super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
                        TextView tv = (TextView) view;
                        if(position % 2 == 1) {
                            // Set the item background color
                            tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#910D3F"));
                        }
                        else {
                            // Set the alternate item background color
                            tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#41061C"));
                        }
                        return view;
                    }
                };

                mySpinner.setPrompt("Select Your Constituency");
                myAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.custom_spinner_item);
                mySpinner.setAdapter(myAdapter);

                //RECEIVE DATA VIA INTENT
                mySpinner.setSelection(getIndex(mySpinner, name));

            }catch (JSONException e){e.printStackTrace();}
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    });


    int socketTimeout = 30000;
    RetryPolicy policy = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeout, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
    stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(policy);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

}

Comment: Hey, Please only post code that we can recreate, and help us understand where the error is at. Posting a huge code isn't helpful.

Comment: I think your bug is with your count variable. As you are doing ++count>1, so when it is called first time, it is equal to 1 and hence the code inside if statement doesn't get called

Comment: @VivekMishra I had implemented that code to prevent the setOnItemSelectedListener from firing when the activity launches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that from API level 3, one can use the onUserInteraction() on an Activity with a boolean value thereby determining the user's interaction.

Find the documentation in the link below.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onUserInteraction()

```
@Override
public void onUserInteraction() {
     super.onUserInteraction();
     userInteracts = true;
}
```

The my adjustment goes as thus in the MainActivity.java

```
mySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        int check = 0;
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            if (IsInteracting) {
                Intent intent = getIntent(); //MainActivity
                String itemSelected = mySpinner.getItemAtPosition(mySpinner.getSelectedItemPosition()).toString();

                //TODO: DONE
                prefManager.spinWriteString(itemSelected);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Constituency News Now Showing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        }
```

Comment: I think my solution is not perfect. I have just noticed that from android 8.0 and up, the new data loads selectively.